# Improvement of matrix calculation in F#

Tags: f#, matrix

I wrote a code to perform some basic Matrix calculation using F#. I would like to know if there are some possible improvements on this code in order to decrease the calculation time. 
Indeed the operations performed are quite basic (multiplication of 2 matrices and transpose mainly) however sizes of the matrix is high (around `10000 * 100000`) leading to a huge calculation duration (few hours).

My questions/remarks are the following :

1. Is there any way to improve the following code? There are many "for
   loops" which may lead to a serious slow down of the algorithm, but I
   don't know how to avoid these "for loops".
2. I created some initial Matrix with initial values at 0 and, in a second time, filled their elements with results. Maybe it is possible to avoid the first step of initialisation.

Here is the algorithm :

```
// I use the #time function to calculate the calculation duration of the algorithm
#time

#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
#r "FSharp.PowerPack.dll"

open System
open System.IO

open Microsoft.FSharp.Math
open System.Collections.Generic

// Algorithm
let matrixCalculation (matA : matrix) (matB : matrix) (matC : matrix) =  

    // First step : Renamed the matrix A and B size to initialize the matrix "matrixCalcul" 
    let nbrOfElementsA = matA.NumRows
    let nbrOfElementsB = matB.NumRows
    let nbrOfCaracteristicsA = matA.NumCols
    let nbrOfCaracteristicsB = matB.NumCols

    // Second step : MatB has to be transposed 
    let tmatB = matB.Transpose

    // Initialisation of the final output named matrixCalcul. A weighted vector is also initialised 
    let mutable matrixCalcul = Matrix.create (nbrOfElementsA + 1) (nbrOfElementsB + 1) 0.            
    let mutable weightedVector = Matrix.create nbrOfCaracteristicsA 1 0.                   

    // The first column of matA and matB represents IDs, and are "copy/past" in matrixCalcul's first colum and first row respectively
    matrixCalcul.[1.. ,0..0] <- matA.[0..,0..0]
    matrixCalcul.[0..0,1 ..] <- matB.[0..,0..0].Transpose

    // Then the core of the matrix named "matrixCalcul" can be calculated
    for j = 0 to (nbrOfElementsB - 1) do
        weightedVector <- matC * tmatB.[1..(nbrOfCaracteristicsB - 1),0..(nbrOfElementsB-1)].Columns(j,1)                       
        for i = 0 to (nbrOfElementsA - 1) do
            let mutable acc  = matA.[0..(nbrOfElementsA - 1),1..(nbrOfCaracteristicsA-1)].Rows(i,1) * weightedVector                
            matrixCalcul.[i+1,j+1] <- (acc.[0,0])
    matrixCalcul


// Two matrix generators (one for matA and matB and another one for matC)

let matrixTestGeneratorAandB nbrOfElements nbrOfCaracteristics = 
    let matrixTestGeneratedAandB = Matrix.create nbrOfElements nbrOfCaracteristics 0.
                                   |> Matrix.mapi (fun i j value -> if j = 0 then float(i + 1) elif j % 2 = 0 then 1. else 0.)
    matrixTestGeneratedAandB

let matrixTestGeneratorC nbrOfElements nbrOfCaracteristics = 
    let matrixTestGeneratedC = Matrix.create nbrOfElements nbrOfCaracteristics 0.
                               |> Matrix.mapi (fun i j value -> if j = 0 then 0. elif j % 2 = 0 then 1. else 0.)
    matrixTestGeneratedC


// Generation of matrixA, matrixB and matrixC

let matrixA = matrixTestGeneratorAandB 100 179

let matrixB = matrixTestGeneratorAandB 100 639

let matrixC = matrixTestGeneratorC 178 638

// Calculation 
matrixCalculation matrixA matrixB matrixC
```

Basically the calculation duration amounts to circa 2 seconds, but if you change the number of `matrixA` and `matrixB` up to `10000`, it can take hour. Just for information, in my algorithm, `matrixC`'s size will remain constant, only matrix A and B can have an increasing number of rows.

If you have any idea of improvement, I take it.

Comment: OK no problem I am on it

Comment: Could you provide a test script for benchmarking and explain more clearly what your code is actually doing?

Comment: My gut reaction would be to remove the matrix creation from the inner most loop.

Comment: I'm thinking this question is better asked on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Have you tried using some matrix library instead?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From your code, it's quite difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve. I think you mean to compute a matrix `d[0..m, 0..n]` as follows:

```
  +---------+-------------------------+
  | 0.0     | b00 b10 ......  b(n-1)0 |
  +---------+-------------------------+
  | a00     | d11 d12 ......  d1n     |
  | a10     | d21 d22 ......  d2n     |
  | ...     | ... ... ......  ...     |
  | ...     | ... ... ......  ...     |
  | ...     | ... ... ......  ...     |
  | a(m-1)0 | dm1 dm2 ......  dmn     |
  +---------+-------------------------+
```

where the core part (the inner matrix `d[1..m, 1..n]`) is a multiplication of three matrices `matA1` (`matA` after trimmed the first columns), `matC` and `matB1` (`matB` after trimmed the first column and transposed).

To understand matrix operation, a good way to go is reasoning on matrix size. Let `ra`, `ca`, `rb`, `cb`, `rc` and `cc` denote the number of rows and columns in `matA`, `matB` and `matC` respectively. The multiplication is among three matrices of size `ra x (ca-1)`, `rc x cc`and `(cb-1) x rb`; this only makes sense if `rc = ca-1` and `cc = cb-1`. We have the resulting matrix `d` of size `(ra+1) x (rb+1)`.

Here is my attempt without using any `for` loop:

```
let calculate (matA : matrix) (matB : matrix) (matC : matrix) = 
    let ra = matA.NumRows
    let ca = matA.NumCols
    let rb = matB.NumRows
    let cb = matB.NumCols
    let matrixCalcul = Matrix.zero (ra+1) (rb+1)

    matrixCalcul.[1.., 0..0] <- matA.[0.., 0..0]
    matrixCalcul.[0..0, 1..] <- matB.[0.., 0..0].Transpose

    matrixCalcul.[1.., 1..] <- (matA.Columns(1, ca-1) * matC) * matB.Columns(1, cb-1).Transpose
    matrixCalcul
```

I have tested with `matA`, `matB` and `matC` of size 200x279, 200x1279 and 278x1238 respectively. Two versions yield the same result and my function is `40x` faster than the original one. There are many reasons for that, but in general a vectorized version has much better performance when it comes to matrix calculation.

Comment: Deserves +10 just for the effort!

Comment: Thank you pad, it's perfectly working. Moreover my question was not very easy to decript... Thank you again